# my App crashes while integrating with the facebook SDK

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-login

[image: screenshot] my app crashes when the facebook login button is clicked it shows FBSDKInternalUtility.m:484 error

here's my code[image]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController ,FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil)
    {
        // User is already logged in, do work such as go to next view controller.
    }
    else
    {
        let loginView : FBSDKLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
        self.view.addSubview(loginView)
        loginView.center = self.view.center
        loginView.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
        loginView.delegate = self
    }
}

// Facebook Delegate Methods

func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {
    print("User Logged In")

    if ((error) != nil)
    {
        // Process error
    }
    else if result.isCancelled {
        // Handle cancellations
    }
    else {
        // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
        // should check if specific permissions missing
        if result.grantedPermissions.contains("email")
        {
            // Do work
        }
    }
}

func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
    print("User Logged Out")
}

func returnUserData()
{
    let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil)
    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

        if ((error) != nil)
        {
            // Process error
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
        else
        {
            print("fetched user: \(result)")
            let userName : NSString = result.valueForKey("name") as! NSString
            print("User Name is: \(userName)")
            let userEmail : NSString = result.valueForKey("email") as! NSString
            print("User Email is: \(userEmail)")
        }
    })
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

i have a bridging header and added it in the Xcode's project build settings but it still shows the error

thanks

Answer (score 6):

I think you may be encountering a iOS9 compatibility issue:

Had a similar issue, I fixed it by updating info.plist with the following:

```html
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

here's the facebook page that describes the changes:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your loginButton function is missing a '{' at the start.

Also I believe your if statement 'if result.grantedPermissions.contains("email")' needs to have an else condition.

Also the states that you describe in your loginButton function probably need to have some body. The states are currently described but there is no code to be executed when either of the described states are reached.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I deleted the libraries and added them from the project "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" and re-linked and it worked.

Hope it helps,
Andoni.